# How to add event in hybrid app using ionic calendar+angularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to add events on selected date using ionic calendar and angularJs. But it should not add that event to native calendar app. How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with [this ionic plugin](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker), it's quite simple and have good documentation.